# How to Pass multiple data array to view Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter and have two small question

1: How can I pass two table data array to view?

```
$data['customers']=$this->customer_model->get_all_customers(); 
        //$products['product']=$this->customer_model->get_all_categories();
        //$this->load->view("customer_view",$data);
        $product['cats']=$this->customer_model->get_all_categories(); 

         $this->loadViews("customer_view", $this->global, $data, $product);
```

But I am getting error

2: I am joining two tables to get two tables data but I am getting only one table data?

```
public function get_all_categories()
{

/*// Get Data from Two tables
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('category');
$this->db->join('customers','customers.categoryID=category.categoryID','Inner');
$query=$this->db->get();
```

please help me to resolve.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
$query=$this->db->get();
```

Should be :

```
$query=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for Passing multi variable to view

**Controller**

```
$data['customers']=$this->customer_model->get_all_customers(); 
$data['cats']=$this->customer_model->get_all_categories(); 


$data ['customers'] = $customers;
        $data ['cats'] = $categories;
    $this->loadViews("customer_view", $this->global,  $data);
```

In view we will use $customers and $categories